# Show certain elements when using common template based on url in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am using on a common template in two pages. I have to show some lines  in one page. So i have added an  if function which will check the current url . It is working for me only once. After coming back to the same url i am getting previous url's value. Then this it is not changing . Below is a sample code. How to achieve this?

Below is my code

Url-  /template1

Template1.html

```
 <template name="template1">
  {{>commontemplate}}
  </template>
```

Url - /template2

Tempalate2.html

```
   <template name="tempalte2">
  {{>commonTemplate}}
 </template>
```

CommonTemplate.html

```
 <template name="commonTemplate">
  {{#if isAdmin 'template1'}}
   <div> hello</div>
  {{else}}
  <div> hai</div>
 {{/if}}
 </template>
```

CommonTemplate.js

```
   Template.CommonTemplate.helpers({
   isAdmin: function (val) {
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    var str = path.split("/");
    return  val === str[1];
   }
 })
```

Comment: what router are using? `flow-router` can help you with that

Comment: yes. I am using flow-router

Comment: I have tried to store url value in flow router by using session and fetch it in the helper function. But same issue still persists. It won't udate after first load.

Comment: so use the official API of `flow-router` no need for Sessions, If you could share full code such as in meteorpad I could help you figure it out.

Comment: Thanks. FlowRouter.current() did the task for me.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's not rerunning is that your helper function has no reactive dependencies.  Normal Javascript variables (like `window.location.pathname`) don't instruct reactive computations (like helper functions) to rerun when their values change.

The two easiest possibilities are:

1. Name your routes and use `FlowRouter.getRouteName()` in the helper function, which *is* reactive.
2. Add the line `FlowRouter.watchPathChange()` to your helper, which doesn't return anything, but does ensure the containing reactive function reruns whenever the path changes. [FlowRouter API](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router).

The other alternative is to simply use CSS.  Have a look at [meteor-london:body-class](https://github.com/meteor-london/body-class), which appends the route name as a class to the body, allowing you to selectively show or hide stuff based on route in your CSS.